# Switch a window in appium by using driver.switchTo().window() it gives org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

Appium version is `1.9.0`
Java client version is `1.6.1`
Android studio version 3.2
chrome driver version is **ChromeDriver** `2.42`
Android mobile device chrome browser version is 69.0 with android version 6.0

Below is my code where i am trying to switch a child window

```
Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles(); // Get all windows working fine

String parentWindow = windows.stream().findFirst().get(); // Get parent window 

Thread.sleep(15000); // Adding static time due to page loading issue

driver.switchTo().window(windows.toArray()[windows.toArray().length-1].toString());
```

> > switch to child window. also `windows.toArray([windows.toArray().length-1].toString()` giving right value but if put that on driver.switchTo.window it throws below exception

**Exception**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: 'name' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: '-PC', ip: '172.16.2.99', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {app: D:\Drive 20-08-2018\H..., appActivity: com.ss.dd.M..., appPackage: com.rr.rr, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: Appium, chromedriverExecutable: D:\Drive 20-08-2018\H..., databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: D:\Drive 20-08-2018\H..., appActivity: com.ii.M..., appPackage: com.pkg, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: Appium, chromedriverExecutable: D:\Drive 20-08-2018\H..., deviceName: InFocus InFocusM500, nativeWebScreenshot: true, newCommandTimeout: 1200, noReset: true, platform: ANDROID, platformName: android}, deviceManufacturer: Infocus, deviceModel: InFocus M500, deviceName: 17789703032114619539, deviceScreenSize: 480x854, deviceUDID: 17789703032114619539, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, nativeWebScreenshot: true, networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 1200, noReset: true, platform: ANDROID, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 6.0, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 4cd7a579-8606-43e8-922b-5a97a6157053
    at com.hp.commercial.framework.common.TestScriptManager.handleTestFailure(TestScriptManager.java:791)
    at com.fd.fdf.fdf.testscripts.fdf.fdf(fd.java:616)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using `stream` API

```
driver.switchTo().window(windows.stream().skip(windows.size()- 2).findFirst().get());
```

Comment: Hi @Amit , Still issue is exists, If you have found any other ways, please let me know, or update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out:

```
String childWindow = (String) windows.toArray()[windows.toArray().length-1];
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
```

Comment: Hi @KnightRadiantS,  still same exception coming, If you have found any other ways, please let me know, or update the answer.

Comment: Can you post the new code you run with above solution and the entire stack trace here, might help more diagnose the problem.